# Lambda resizing image in S3 bucket with sharp corrupting image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, sharp

I have followed [this AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html) to add an `S3` trigger that resizes an image using `sharp` and puts it in a different bucket. This all seems to work fine. The problem I have is with fetching the new image using a `GET` endpoint through `API Gateway`.

The file returned seems larger than it should be and is not a valid image.
If I download the file directly from the `S3` UI, the image is fine, which suggests there's something going on with the `API Gateway` (I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html#api-root-get-as-s3-get-service) to set that up)

Now here's the strange part...

If I manually upload an image to the bucket that stores the resized images, then download the image through `API Gateway`, IT WORKS! So the gateway appears fine.

Why would the download seem corrupted only when the image has been resized and downloaded through the `API Gateway`?

EDIT: -

If I change my `GET` gateway to use the original bucket that images are uploaded to, images are downloaded fine.

Comment: Is it base64-encoded in the bad download? Also be aware of the option to use S3 pre-signed URLs to retrieve S3 content.

Comment: No, it appears as raw data when viewed through `Postman`

Comment: Looking at `CloudWatch` logs, it's saying that it can't convert it from `Base64`. A successful response shows data before transformations is `[Binary Data]` wheres a bad request shows the actual data as ute. So somewhere I think the resize script is putting it in a different format.

Comment: I have fixed it :) The script from the `AWS` tutorial was setting the Content-Type to `image`. I've changed it to `image\jpeg` and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to lie with the resizing script setting the `Content-Type` to `image`. I changed it to `image/jpeg` and it worked.

This might actually be related to the `S3` setting of allowable data type. Maybe if I'd just added `image` instead of `image/jpeg` it would work, but I didn't test that.